# Convert a PDF/Image score into a programmatic format

Tags: open-source, pdf, music, offline, media-converter

Having a [music score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheet_music) in PDF or image, format, containing a melody, what tools are available to convert it into a programmatic format (JSON or so)?

The tools should:

- work offline (installable on a local machine)
- have a library API or being accessible with a bash command (e.g. `foo score.pdf -o melody.json`)
- be free (in terms of freedom)
- should accept a pdf/image input and export any programmatic output that could be converted in a JSON structure
- `+1` if they work in browser, on the client side. Not a requirement, but I'd prefer that.
- `+1` if they can be used as NodeJS libraries. Also, not a requirement, but  I'd prefer that since my app is written in NodeJS.
- preferably, cross-platform, running on Linux being a requirement.

Comment: I am sure that you realize that this is a toughie. Not being musical, I can't even begin to imagine how you will represent music as JSON data :-)  However, https://audiveris.kenai.com/ "processes the image of a music sheet to automatically provide symbolic music information in MusicXML standard" - and from there it shouldn't be too difficult to get it into JSON.  See also this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675077/ocr-for-sheet-music

Comment: @Mawg I already defined a JSON format which my scripts can play beautifully. Do they have an online service so I can send the image/pdf file and they give me the xml response? That would be also nice. How can I do that? After having the XML it would be easy to interpret it and convert it into my format.

Comment: Well, they have a large API at https://audiveris.kenai.com/docs/api/index.html  the site is quite informative and, alas, you will understand more of it than I do. I just hope that it can help.   Btw, the have a "help wanted" for "Coupling with MuseScore (http://musescore.org/) to edit, print, play, etc"